# Select an item on a list with DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input-wrapper')
```

> Result

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy08G.png)

Is there a way to select the second item of an ion-list by doing a dom manipulation ?

Tried with selected index didn't work

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('input-wrapper')[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

use can select the second item with index, check the snippet

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('input-wrapper');
Object.keys(el).forEach(item=>{
 el[item].addEventListener('click' ,()=>{
  el[item].children[0].checked = !el[item].children[0].checked
  console.log(el[item]);  
})
})
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">1 label <input type="radio" value="select"> Label</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">2 label <input type="radio" value="select"> Label</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">3 label
  <input type="radio" value="select"> Label
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">4 label <input type="radio" value="select"> Label </div>
<div class="input-wrapper">5 label <input type="radio" value="select"> Label </div>
<div class="input-wrapper">6 label <input type="radio" value="select"> Label </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to select the radio-button ?

Comment: where is radio button in yout html, provide html or snippet

Comment: @julia456124645 check the snippet now

Comment: Awesome i can get my element but how to select it ? ( act like i did it with the mouse )

Comment: add a event listener

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it please ?

Comment: @julia456124645, check the snippet now

Comment: @julia456124645, if the answer is helpful, please vote